# c++ pointer being freed was not allocated error

Tags: c++, pointers

I am practcing c++'s new/delete, hashfunction and linked.

I made a practice by myself.

I have a struct which is

```
typedef struct student
{
    int id;
    string fName;
    string lName;
    student * nextStudent;
}Student;
```

Then in main function, I define an array of student

```
Student * table = new Student [10];
```

I have my own hash function which takes the id, and change to  0-9.
I want to add a student I do following

```
void addStudent(int studentId, string firstName, string lastName, Student  *table)
{
    // using hash function, convert the id into hashed id
    int hashedID = hashFunction( studentId );   

        Student * pointer = &table[hashedID];

        while(pointer->nextStudent !=NULL){
            pointer = pointer->nextStudent;
        }

        // once we reach to the student who has NULL in nextStudent
        // add student
        Student *tmp = new Student;
        tmp->id = studentId;
        tmp->fName = firstName;
        tmp->lName = lastName;
        tmp->nextStudent = NULL;

        // link
        pointer->nextStudent = tmp;

}
```

I tested it, it seems fine.

The problem is deletion.
Since student variables are stored in dynamic memeory,
I need to use delete.

The following is my code.

```
void deleteAll(Student *table, int len)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        Student* tmp = &table[i];

        // delete student info except the last one
        while ( tmp -> nextStudent !=NULL){
            Student* tmp2;
            tmp2 = tmp;
            tmp = tmp->nextStudent;
            delete tmp2;
         }
    }
}
```

I visited every student varialbes ane do the deletion.
I cannot find any probelm in my deletion funtion...

This is what I got after run..

```
malloc: *** error for object 0x7f85f1404b18: pointer being freed was not allocated
```

I have no clue what I have done wrong..
Can you help me?

**EDIT...**

As you guys metion 
I added "delete [] table" in the main funtion..
Also, I remove "delete tmp" in deleteAll function; i think "delete [] table" will handle that part.

Still does not work..

By the way I forgot to added initTable function in the initial post.
initTable initialize the table...

```
void initTable (Student *table, int len)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i)
    {
        table[i].nextStudent = NULL;
    }
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: How do you initialize `table` after you allocate it?

Comment: `table[i]` wasn't allocated individually, it was allocated as part of an array. All subsequent students in the linked list can be deleted with `delete`, but `table[i]` must only be deleted by deleting the whole array (`delete[] table;`).

Comment: @JonathanPotter that should be written up as an answer

Comment: @JonathanPotter I edited my post to cover your very valid point, which I overlooked at first reading. Let me know if you think I "borrowed" too much since that was never my intention.

Comment: @dxiv That's fine, in fact +1 for taking the time to make it an answer.

Comment: I have a function that initialize the table. The function set nextStudent to NULL. As @JonathanPotter mentioned, I added delete [] table in the main function. I also remove the "delete tmp" in deleteAll function since delete[] is going to handle the deletion. Still does not work..

Comment: @HanJo.Jang  The updated `deleteAll` that you posted still attempts to delete `&table[i]` with the same wrong comment `delete student info except the last one`. Please re-read @JonathanPotter's comment more carefully, also the answer I posted.

Comment: Thank you for you help. Now I am fully understande what I misunderstood.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `nextStudent` field is never initialized, so all 10 elements created here have it pointing to unknown values.

```
Student * table = new Student [10];
```

This causes `addStudent` to loop until some `pointer->nextStudent` hits a NULL value by chance, then overwrite memory it doesn't own (unless it hits the lucky NULL on the first iteration).

```
while(pointer->nextStudent !=NULL) { ... }
```

The 'student` struct (btw, why the typedef?) should have a constructor to at least do this.

```
student::student() : nextStudent(NULL) { }
```

**[ EDIT ]** The other issue that @JonathanPotter duly pointed in a comment is that the head of each of the 10 `student` lists is a member of the `table` array. It is *not* dynamically allocated, and should *not* be individually deleted.

The qucik/easy fix would be to add a `student` destructor to recursively delete child nodes:

```
student::~student() { if(nextStudent) delete nextStudent; }
```

Then `deleteAll` would reduce to:

```
void deleteAll(student *table, int len)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        student *tmp = &table[i];
        if(tmp->nextStudent) delete tmp->nextStudent;
    }
    // this leaves the dynamically allocated table[] in place
    // to delete it as well, just `delete [] table;`
}
```

However, such recursion may become impracticable once the lists grow large, and should better be rewritten as an iteration (without the recursive destructor).

```
student::~student() { }

// ...

void deleteAll(student *table, int len)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        student *tmp = &table[i];

        // delete student info except the *first* one
        for(student *tmp2; tmp2 = tmp->nextStudent; )
        {
            tmp->nextStudent = tmp2->nextStudent;
            delete tmp2;
        }
    }
    // this leaves the dynamically allocated table[] in place
    // to delete it as well, just `delete [] table;`
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Then in main function, I define an array of student
>
> Student * table = new Student [10];

First of all you are creating array of Student not Student*. And late you are trying to delete not allocated values. This is the reason of your program behavior.

To create pointer of array of pointers Student* you need the following:

```
Student** table =  new Student*[10];
```

Than change your functions arguments from `Student* table` to `Student** table` and continue research. 
Also do not forget to delete table using `delete[] table;`
Good Luck.